# How to write a case statement with multiple whens that bring out more than one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I have a case statement which I am using to create a column from several columns, depending on the answer in each column. I need to show a new row for each time the answer is 1 in any of the columns, but at the moment it is only showing one row for the first one that matches.

Please see the code and examples. Thanks

I am using SQL Server 17
I am querying from tables I have no access rights to, so cannot create tables etc. I am looking to query and not declare and set values.

```
      ID,
      CASE
          WHEN ORG1 = 1 THEN 'ORG1'
          WHEN ORG2 = 1 THEN 'ORG2'
          WHEN ORG3 = 1 THEN 'ORG3'
          WHEN ORG4 = 1 THEN 'ORG4'
          WHEN ORG5 = 1 THEN 'ORG5'
      else 'None' end as ORG

FROM TBL
```

current table looks like:

```
ID  ORG1   ORG2   ORG3   ORG4   ORG5
1    1      0      0       0     1
2    0      1      1       0     0
3    0      0      1       0     1
4    0      1      0       0     0
5    0      0      0       1     0
6    1      0      0       1     0
```

What I want it the outcome to look like is:

```
ID   ORG
1    ORG1
1    ORG5
2    ORG2    
2    ORG3
3    ORG3
3    ORG5
4    ORG2
5    ORG4
6    ORG1
6    ORG4
```

What I am getting with my code is:

```
ID   ORG
1    ORG1
2    ORG2   
3    ORG3
4    ORG2
5    ORG4
6    ORG1
```

Comment: That's a `case` _expression_, not statement...

Comment: You're looking for UNPIVOT. Simply UNION ALL each org column.

Comment: _"...querying from tables I have no access rights to"_ - what does that even mean? If this is a limitation of the tool you are using, then specify this up front rather than making demands and complaints to the people offering **free** help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple approach would be a `union all` like so:

```
select * from
(
  select id, 'ORG1' as org from tbl where org1=1
  union all
  select id, 'ORG2' as org from tbl where org1=2
  union all
  select id, 'ORG3' as org from tbl where org1=3
  union all
  select id, 'ORG4' as org from tbl where org1=4
  union all
  select id, 'ORG5' as org from tbl where org1=5
) as tmp
```

I am guessing that you want to filter out all `0` columns. If not just delete the `where clause`

Comment: I think an alias name is required for the table.

Comment: This doesn't do what I need as it still brings out the number, so I just get a column of 1's not the name of the column.

Comment: @BeckyPurland - You're right! Sorry I jumped the gun on that one. Have a look at my edited answer...

Comment: Thanks Ted, I did something similar to this and it worked. The org = just needs to be 1 each time, not 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this.

```
-- Sample Data
DECLARE @TBL TABLE (ID  INT, ORG1 INT,  ORG2 INT,  ORG3  INT, ORG4 INT,  ORG5 INT)
INSERT INTO @TBL VALUES
(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1),
(2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0),
(3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1),
(4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0),
(5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0),
(6, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0),
(7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)


SELECT ID, UNPVT.ORG FROM @TBL
UNPIVOT( VAL FOR ORG IN ([ORG1], [ORG2], [ORG3], [ORG4], [ORG5])) UNPVT
WHERE VAL = 1
```

Result:

```
ID          ORG
----------- ------------
1           ORG1
1           ORG5
2           ORG2
2           ORG3
3           ORG3
3           ORG5
4           ORG2
5           ORG4
6           ORG1
6           ORG4
```

If you have cases which all columns are "0"

```
SELECT ID, UNPVT.ORG FROM 
    (SELECT *, 
        ([ORG1] + [ORG2] + [ORG3] + [ORG4] + [ORG5])^1 AS [None]
     FROM @TBL) SRC
UNPIVOT( VAL FOR ORG IN ([ORG1], [ORG2], [ORG3], [ORG4], [ORG5], [None])) UNPVT
WHERE VAL = 1
```

Result:

```
ID          ORG
----------- ------------
1           ORG1
1           ORG5
2           ORG2
2           ORG3
3           ORG3
3           ORG5
4           ORG2
5           ORG4
6           ORG1
6           ORG4
7           None
```

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure how this works as ORG is not in the table. So, SELECT ID, ORG FROM TBL does not work. The columns in the table are org1, org2...etc.

Comment: without case statement how u generate org1, org2, org3??

Comment: @serkan does it return the sample output?

Comment: @BeckyPurland ORG is just alias for your column names for UNPIVOT. not a real column name.

Comment: @fa06 at the question it prints column names that have 1 value. If you use UNPIVOT function you can get column names and corresponding values. And after unpivot you can apply to filter to bring just "1" values.

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin except for all "0" columns, it returns the same output.

Answer (score 0):

do unpivot after using case expression

```
select id,org from (
select id, case when org1=1 then 'org1' end as og1,
case when org2=1 then 'org2' end as og2,
case when org3=1 then 'org3' end as og3,
case when org4=1 then 'org4' end as og4,
case when org5=1 then 'org5' end as og5

 from table_name
 ) a unpivot (org for value in (og1,og2,og3,og4,og5)) p

id  org
1   org1
1   org5
2   org2
2   org3
3   org3
3   org5
4   org2
5   org4
6   org1
6   org4
```

[here demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=60e6a9e197e74683dd3c2f63efc6a14b)

Comment: The case statements in this code are not completed, they need an end in order to work

Answer (score 0):

this is another approach

```
declare @Tbl as table (id int, org1 int, org2 int, org3 int, org4 int, org5 int)

insert into @Tbl values 
(1,1,0,0,0,1),
(2,0,1,1,0,0),
(3,0,0,1,0,1),
(4,0,1,0,0,0),
(5,0,0,0,1,0),
(6,1,0,0,1,0)

select * from @Tbl

declare @temp as table (org varchar(5))
insert into @temp values
('org1'),('org2'),('org3'),('org4'),('org5')

select * from @temp


select * from @Tbl cross join @temp
where (org='org1' and org1=1) or
(org='org2' and org2=1) or
(org='org3' and org3=1) or
(org='org4' and org4=1) or
(org='org5' and org5=1)
order by id
```

Comment: Like I said in my question, I don't want to see declare and set answers and I don't have the ability to insert into a table. Please read the whole question.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `cross apply`.  However, you need additional logic for the `'NONE'` value -- even though your sample data doesn't include any examples:

```
SELECT t.ID, v.ORG
FROM TBL t CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES ('ORG1', ORG1),
             ('ORG2', ORG2),
             ('ORG3', ORG3),
             ('ORG4', ORG4),
             ('ORG5', ORG5)
     ) V(ORG, val),
WHERE val = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT t.ID, 'None'
FROM TBL
WHERE ORG1 = 0 AND ORG2 = 0 AND ORG3 = 0 AND ORG4 = 0 AND ORG5 = 0;
```

Or without the `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT t.ID, v.ORG
FROM TBL t CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES ('ORG1', ORG1),
             ('ORG2', ORG2),
             ('ORG3', ORG3),
             ('ORG4', ORG4),
             ('ORG5', ORG5),
             ('NONE', (CASE WHEN ORG1 = 0 AND ORG2 = 0 AND ORG3 = 0 AND ORG4 = 0 AND ORG5 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))
     ) V(ORG, val),
WHERE val = 1
```